# How do I create a subset of a JSON file using key values that exist in both using getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I have a large JSON file that I want to use to create a subset using vars that I'll be storing in localStorage. I prefer jQuery but other approaches are welcomed.

The id (which will exist in both places) will be used to match and determine that the keys/values should be part of the new subset.

The "master" JSON file is structured similar to this:

```
{
    "myStuff": [


        {
            "id": "53b0c01de4b0deedb5c9015f",
            "brief": "Joe's Stuff",
            "author": "Joe"
        },


        {
            "id": "545fb8c4e4b03cfb303de9f2",
            "brief": "Jim's Stuff",
            "author": "Jim"
        },

        {
            "id": "54676ae4e4b09ffed41ffc7c",
            "brief": "Mary's Stuff",
            "author": "Mary"
        }

    ]
}
```

I have flexibility in how the items that will determine the subset are presented.It will always contain multiple values. Those are "id" value to match an existing "id" value in the master JSON file.

For example, I can get a string out of localStorage that would look like this:

```
{"id1":"545fb8c4e4b03cfb303de9f2","id2":"54676ae4e4b09ffed41ffc7c"}
```

or as simple as this:

```
 545fb8c4e4b03cfb303de9f2, 54676ae4e4b09ffed41ffc7c
```

Suggestions to which approach may be better are welcomed.

So, in this case, The subset should return just the stuff from Jim and Mary and ignore Joe.

```
{
    "myStuffSubset": [


        {
            "id": "545fb8c4e4b03cfb303de9f2",
            "brief": "Jim's Stuff",
            "author": "Jim"
        },

        {
            "id": "54676ae4e4b09ffed41ffc7c",
            "brief": "Mary's Stuff",
            "author": "Mary"
        }

    ]
}
```

Please let me know if I've missed something in the explanation. And, I find fiddles help me learn the best. Thanks!

Comment: I've created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ceu0zbrIEZ9zS2yquCgQ?p=preview) for you, let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: @Buzinas Thanks! I'm new to plnkr so need a little time to review. The "master" JSON file will not reside in localStorage (will be on a server) so I got confused when I quickly reviewed.

Comment: I've updated the plnkr to get the master JSON from a file.

Comment: @Buzinas Thanks! I'm trying to understand what's going on—but not there yet. Long day, long night.

Comment: @Buzinas Made some good progress. Will be back to you if I have questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Buzinas "searchInLocalStorage" won't apply when reading from a JSON file—but I don't understand how to fix.

Comment: @Buzinas Yay! Made some mods and it's working with localStorage or external JSON file. Thanks for the help! Please post your rec as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: alright, man, done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ceu0zbrIEZ9zS2yquCgQ?p=preview) for you.

Basically, the filter function will get the string separated by commas and search inside your JSON:

```
function search(str, obj) {
  var arr = str.split(',');
  return obj.myStuff.filter(function(o) {
      return arr.indexOf(o.id) > -1;
  });
}
```